# Change data frame in Google sheets using Query function

Tags: google-sheets, transpose

I'd like to know how I can change the data frame from

```
name|type

A| main

B| side

C| side

D| main
```

to

```
main|side|side

A|B|C

D|B|C
```

In Google Sheets. The main reason is to help our chef visualize the dish combo while keeping a data frame that is easy to sort and analyze. The best I can do is to use a query/pivot function, but I get this instead:

```
name|main|side

A | 0 | blank

D | 0 | blank

B | blank | 0

C | blank | 0
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: What do you mean by data frame? Also, is each row you are showing here a cell? Could you please share a sample of your sheet with non sensitive information so that we can understand better your question?